# Remove an option from dynamically-generated drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a button that generates a dynamic form that contains 3 dropdowns. The selected options from the first form and the new generated form should not be duplicates. Same goes for all the forms. What I want is to remove the option from the last dropdown to avoid duplication. For example if I select "option A" and "2nd option A" and "3rd option A" from the first form, and I select "option A" and "2nd option A" from the second form, the 3rd drop down from this 2nd form shouldn't have "3rd option A". So basically I want jQuery to delete option of the 3rd drop down from the newly generated form.

```js
var i = 1;
$("#addForm").click(function() {
  i++;
  $("#myForm").append('<select id="dropdown1' + i + '"><option value="option A">option A</option><option value="option B">option B</option><option value="option C">option C</option></select><select id="dropdown2' + i + '"><option value="2nd option A">2nd option A</option><option value="2nd option B">2nd option B</option><option value="2nd option C">2nd option C</option></select><select id="dropdown3' + i + '">option value="3rd option A">3rd option A</option><option value="3rd option B">3rd option B</option><option value="3rd option C">3rd option C</option></select>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div id="myForm">
    <select id="dropdown11">
      <option value="option A">option A</option>
      <option value="option B">option B</option>
      <option value="option C">option C</option>
    </select>
    <select id="dropdown21">
      <option value="2nd option A">2nd option A</option>
      <option value="2nd option B">2nd option B</option>
      <option value="2nd option C">2nd option C</option>
    </select>
    <select id="dropdown31">
      <option value="3rd option A">3rd option A</option>
      <option value="3rd option B">3rd option B</option>
      <option value="3rd option C">3rd option C</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button type="button" id="addForm">ADD</button>
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the research you've done into the issue, and the attempts you've made based on that research.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the element `data-child/group` as identifiers.
Ill show you an example of what you requested. It will only show values based on the selected value in one of the select-boxes.

You will also need to edit your `#addform` function to make my example work with your dynamically added input fields.

```js
var i = 1;
$("#addForm").click(function() {
  i++;
  $("#myForm").append('<select id="dropdown1' + i + '"><option value="option A">option A</option><option value="option B">option B</option><option value="option C">option C</option></select><select id="dropdown2' + i + '"><option value="2nd option A">2nd option A</option><option value="2nd option B">2nd option B</option><option value="2nd option C">2nd option C</option></select><select id="dropdown3' + i + '">option value="3rd option A">3rd option A</option><option value="3rd option B">3rd option B</option><option value="3rd option C">3rd option C</option></select>');
});

$("[data-child]").change(function() {
  const selectedGroup = $(this).val();
  var $childSelect = $("#" + $(this).attr("data-child"));
  value = $childSelect.find("option").hide()
    .filter(function(i, e) {
      return $(e).val().startsWith(selectedGroup)
    }).show().eq(0).val();
  $childSelect.val(value);
  $childSelect.trigger("change");
});
$("[data-child]").eq(0).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div id="myForm">
    <select data-child="dropdown11">
      <option value="A">option A</option>
      <option value="B">option B</option>
      <option value="C">option C</option>
    </select>
    <select id="dropdown11" data-child="dropdown21">
      <option data-group="A" value="AA">2nd option A</option>
      <option data-group="B" value="BB">2nd option B</option>
      <option data-group="C" value="CC">2nd option C</option>
    </select>
    <select id="dropdown21" data-child="dropdown31">
      <option data-group="AA" value="AAA">3rd option A</option>
      <option data-group="BB" value="BBB">3rd option B</option>
      <option data-group="CC" value="CCC">3rd option C</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button type="button" id="addForm">ADD</button>
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

**Advanced option menu (Hide/show based on selection)**

https://codepen.io/crezzur/pen/NWxVqYO